# How to display the node details on clicking it in ReactJS (I am making the nodes using storm react diagram)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nodes

[I shall be able to see node details (text, height, width, position x and) upon clicking the node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIGFn.png)

Comment: Please provide the code what you have tried so far.

Comment: Here's the code inside render function. Basically I am dragging and dropping nodes of different shapes using srd .. what I need is to display the details of a selected node on a form .. code link : https://codeshare.io/5vNoZm

Comment: @Lasitha did you find any solution?